# Add custom button to wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I need to add custom button(like update wishlist, shere wishlist ...) to(frontend) "my account -> my wishlist". Please help me!

```
<wedding_gifts_index>
    <label>Customer My Account My Wishlist</label>
    <!-- Mage_Wishlist -->
    <update handle="customer_account" />
    <reference name="content">
  <block type="wedding/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.gifts" template="wedding/button/gifts.phtml" />
    </reference>
</wedding_gifts_index>
```

Answer (score 3):

This code should work:

```
<wishlist_index_index>
    <reference name="customer.wishlist.buttons">
        <block type=“wedding/customer_wishlist_button" name="customer.wishlist.button.gifts" template=“wedding/button/gifts.phtml" />
    </reference>
</wishlist_index_index>
```